# Git for Windows 7

Tags: php, git, netbeans

My OS is: Windows 7 Ultimate and IDE is Netbeans. Want to work with 2-3 devs on PHP projects. After research I found that it's possible with GIT. Found [this](http://gitstack.com/) solution. But it's installing apache server. (I don't need any web server: I already have one - IIS7). Is there any free solution (I mean not only GIT, maybe something else) that will work with Netbeans and allows to work with group of developers?

Comment: You don't need a web server to use GIT, you can use GIT over ssh, but I am not sure how you would set up the origin repo on windows.

Comment: You could use a web service like Github or BitBucket instead of running your own git server.

Comment: @Jay As I told earlier, first off, Github doesn't allow private projects for free, second off, what if my project is confidential, and I don't want to upload it to any public project server? I want to find  some solution that I will use ONLY between small dev group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of running your own Git server, why not use [bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org)? It will give you a Git server that you can share with up to 5 people, working on an unlimited number of projects and it is free.

Installing and running a private Git server is not worth it.

Comment: for ex, Github  doesn't allow private projects for free

Comment: Yes, @epic_syntax. For small development teams, bitbucket is a huge win. I primarily use it for Mercurial, but the recent addition of Git support is excellent, too.

Comment: And what if my project is confidential, and I don't want to upload it to any public project server?

Comment: Mercurial? How to use it? Can I install it on Windows?

Comment: I have many confidential projects that I host on bitbucket. They are not visible to anyone who I have not invited to be part of the project team. They know a great deal more than I do about setting up Git and Mercurial servers, so they are likely to come up with a more secure solution than I am.

Comment: Mercurial is a DVCS, like Git; although, it is generalyl regarded as more Windows-friendly than Git because it is written in Python. As far as I know, there is still effort under way to create a Windows-native port of Git. Joel Spolsky created a really wonderful introduction to Mercurial (and DVCS ideas in general): http://hginit.com.

Comment: Mercurial is flawed in it's handling of branching. Stick with Git.

Answer (score 1):

For an internal hosting solution I find that Gitolite running on an Ubuntu Server VM with the max secure connection setting bumped up to 100 works really fast! Admin is a breeze as well.

Comment: Let's say all other devs working with IDE like Netbeans. Again, how do you give access to other users over internet to repo?

Comment: Once you're on linux, you're in the realm of existing documentation: http://book.git-scm.com/4_setting_up_a_public_repository.html http://book.git-scm.com/4_setting_up_a_private_repository.html

Comment: This works so well. We're a .net shop and are VERY happy with it. We use a modern Branch-per-Feature regiment (see more here: http://dymitruk.com/blog/2012/02/05/branch-per-feature/)

Comment: Let's say I installed ubuntu on Virtual Box. What's next? Xan we discuss it via skype?

Comment: Just install gitolite. Sitaram is usually on the git irc channel but it's quite straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use TortoiseGit and it's good enough for me. However, a better idea might be to buy a cheap VPS (git doesn't need high specs) and set up your git repo on that.

Comment: TortoiseGit? As far as I know it's not server, but client right? And how to give access to other users over internet to repo created by Tortoise?

Comment: Yes and no. Depends what's the environment you're using it in. If all your job is over shared disks in LAN, then it's enough.

Comment: My projects are located in local disk. IDE is Netbeans and OS: Windows 7 ultimate with IIS7. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes. On my local Win7 machine I create, manage and use git repos with Tortoise only.

Comment: How do you give access to other users over internet to repo created by Tortoise?

Comment: Ah. Now that's where Tortoise is not enough ;) Like I said, it's good when all your work (including other devs) is on local network and shared disks. For internet... hmmm... you might try Dropbox :P

Comment: My question is still unanswered:(( So there is no solution to work over internet?

Comment: Adam Dymitruk suggests a VM solution - an excellent idea IMHO. I suggest a VPS. There's plenty solutions. Remember that git is distributed versioning system. Your local repo and your main project repo don't need to (and shouldn't!) be the same repository.

Comment: Just to add. Command line is best for git. GUI is nice, but you are giving up command history, scriptability, piping, grepping, etc.

Comment: It's not like you can do all of these from Windows' command line ;)